# How to match string contains [ followed by any number greater than 0?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match string that contains **[** followed by  **number greater than 0**.

For example my regex pattern should match strings like:

> Sample.3cb11b[1].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2
>   Sample.3cb11b[28].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2

and should not match

> Sample.3cb11b[0].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2

I have tried Something  like `".*\\[[1-9].*"`.

Comment: in my case it will not be since its represents  an array

Comment: "I tried multiple regex" your question may receive a more positive response if you show what you tried.

Comment: Just saying but why `0` is not a valid index for an array ?

Comment: @AxelH It is a valid index. but in my case based on this condition i  will execute some other code

Comment: Well in my case that wouldnt be the case. But how to  match  something like [13]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: `.*\[0*[1-9][0-9]*\].*` ?

Simple test program:

```
    String[] lines = {
        "Sample.3cb11b[1].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2",
        "Sample.3cb11b[28].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2",
        "Sample.3cb11b[0].books.addressDetail.addrDetail2"};
    for (String line: lines) {
        System.out.println(line + ": "
                + line.matches(".*\\[0*[1-9][0-9]*\\].*"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this regex out and it seems to work:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*).([0-9a-z]*)(\[[1-9][0-9]*?\])(.[a-zA-Z0-9]*){3}  // this is very exact, maybe too much

.*\[[1-9][0-9]*\].*  // this seems to also work, but only cares about the 'greater than 0' part
```

Here is the link to the [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/qFdZ52/4).

Comment: you were absolutely right, i edited my answer accordingly, thanks for the advice <3